# Force HTTPS in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security, https

It seems that setting server.ssl.enabled in an Spring Boot application forces all requests to use HTTPS. Also, from [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-https) and other articles (like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https#mixing)), it seems that requiresSecure() is for forcing HTTPS. What's their relation and when should each one be used?

p.s. When I use server.ssl.enabled=true, it seems that HTTPS is enforced on all pages regardless of the fact that I have set requiresInsecure(). And, when server.ssl.enabled is not set, setting requiresSecure() didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [[1]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server.ssl.enabled), default value of server.ssl.enabled is true. So when server.ssl.enabled is not set, it is still taken as true. requiresSecure is used to make sure, only https get used (there by avoiding http request).

The main usage of server.ssl.enabled is to use in combination with server.ssl.key-store/key-store-apssworrd to enable ssl for embedded Tomcat.

Comment: I tried to answer this question my self :) but was unsure if it was possible to override the ```server.ssl.enabled``` setting with ```requiresSecure```  / ```requiresInsecure```.

Comment: @charybr I use Spring boot and embedded tomcat. It seems that in this case server.ssl.enabled is not true by default, because when I set it to true, it requires https, and when not set, does not require. However, how does this answer my question? When should we use requiresSecure and when should we use server.ssl.enabled?

Comment: server.ssl.enabled without requiresSecure allows both http and https. Where as requiresSecure allows only https.

Comment: According to my testings, it seemed that requiresSecure enforces HTTPS (No HTTP).